# How to map subdomain root to domain folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a subdomian set up that I want to point to a specific directory.

```
cdn.domain.com
```

I want `cdn.domain.com` to point to `domain.com/wp-content/`, but not as a redirect, as that will just show `cdn.domain.com/wp-content/`.

I want to set the domain root, so that when I write `cdn.domain.com` it wil display the files located at `domain.com/wp-content/`.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this?

Comment: Are both domain/subdomain on the same server and share the same document root?

Comment: @JonLin Yes they are and they do :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted to accomplish with the following code in the .htaccess file. :)

```
# Rewrite all requests for wp-content from cdn, so they are fetched from the right place
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.responseretail\.no

# Prevent an endless loop frm ever happening

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content
RewriteRule (.+) /wp-content/$1 [L]

# Redirect http://cdn.domian.com/ to the main page (in case a user tries it)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```